# Mysql Query count

Tags: php, mysql

I wnat all the records in table belonging to a set and where a particular friend_id doesn't exist not more than twice

something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE count(`friend_id`) < 2 and friend_id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

`SELECT * FROM friends where friend_id in (1,2,3,4) group by friend_id having count(friend_id) < 2`

Comment: `friend_id` condition need to be moved to `where`